# Add/append data to specific row/cell of an existing CSV file

Tags: java, csv

I'm trying to append a value to a specific row in a csv file but append'd default is to add the value at the end of the csv file. Not exactly sure how to tell it to append at the end of a specific row. My code looks like the following:

```
try {
        writer = new FileWriter(csvFile ,true);
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
            String[] id = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            if(id[0].equals("1")){
                writer.append(",");
                writer.append("Success");
                System.out.println("Done");
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

The goal is to make the program add "success" where the csv row id is equal to 1. Current result is:

```
Id,Name,Sex,Age
1,Nick,Male,23
2,Dick,Male,25,Success
```

What I would like is:

```
Id,Name,Sex,Age
1,Nick,Male,23,Success
2,Dick,Male,25
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: perhaps flush the writer once you append the success?

Comment: I've tried this and unfortunately it doesn't work. Still appends at the end of the document.

Comment: I think we need a little more to go on. Can you post more of your code?

Comment: yeah we will need more info, but perhaps you can read in the text file and each line gets stored as an arraylist and when you append the success you add it to the arraylist and then when your program finishes it will write to the file you opened?

Comment: You likely have to read the whole thing in and rewrite the whole thing out with your changes. Append doesn't exactly what it says it will do, it appends at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just append to the end of a line and expect the following lines to stay where they are. Think about the structure of a text file, e.g. one containing the following lines:

```
one
two
```

This file is contains the following sequence of characters:

"o", "n", "e", "\n", "t", "w", "o", "\n"

Now, if you add more characters at the end of line 1, you will overwrite line 2.

Therefore, when you insert characters at the end of a line, you need to shift the remainder of the file to make space. That means you have to copy the contents of the remainder of the file, write your ", Success" string, then copy the saved characters back to the file.

But you're creating a FileWriter with the append flag set to true. That means every write appends to the end of the file. What you need to do, instead of appending, is mark the position where you need to write, and start writing at that position. Perhaps the easiest class for doing this is RandomAccessFile.

Answer (score 0):

Since CSV rows are terminated by a CRLF (or just LF), you can just read the entire contents of the file into a string and use a regular expression to replace CRLF with successCRLF.

The regular expression would be something like this:

1.*(\r\n)

Giving you \r\n as a numbered capture group.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can achieve this** but not straight forward ....
you need to read and append your data at beginning then write as new file, this will override .

Find below example:
1 - Read file, keep header to separate then content to separate
2 - add you new content/row data to list of beginning
3 - add header to beginning as we want header should be first
4 - then write whole data to .csv file
Code(You need add jar/dependency in pom for CSVWritter/CSVReader) -

```
   try {
        FileReader filereader = new FileReader(file);

        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(filereader).build();
        String[] header = csvReader.readNext();
        List<String[]> allData = csvReader.readAll();
        FileWriter outputfile = new FileWriter(file, false);
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(outputfile);

        String[] data = {"test1", "test2"};
        allData.add(0,data);
        allData.add(0,header);
        for (String[] dt : allData){
            writer.writeNext(dt);
        }
        // closing writer connection
        writer.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Enjoy :)